# bundler: failed to load command: spring (/bin/spring)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, spring, bundle

¡Hi!

When I tried to create a new project on rails with Mysql

```
rails new appnameywea --database mysql
```

Its fails

```
create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies............................................
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Installing mysql2 0.4.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160828-12619-1uphiih.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.2
Using sprockets 3.7.0
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'` succeeds before bundling.
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'mysql2 (< 0.5, >= 0.3.13)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `each'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:200:in `start'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:184:in `resolve'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    bundler: failed to load command: spring (/bin/spring)
```

And when i run this ...

```
  gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160828-13121-162bkye.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate                 an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

   Gem files will remain installed in /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/yukan/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
```

In short, it fails to load the 'spring' command, and ... I know what it is but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm a novice at this and i don't know what i'm doing, so please, sorry if this question is obvious!

PS: Yes, i install the 'gem mysql2'
PS2: The 'bundle install' also fails for the same problem: spring
PS3: I tried to create a project without --database mysql and explodes because don't have the 'gem mysql2' WHEN I INSTALLED THEM ; -;

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed library `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Try to install via command:

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: Ow, my mistake!
I work on fedora 24, so, i search about that rpm and i found this ... 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=456207
I try to install it and i have conflicts, but ... thx for the help